# How do I start a service thread using the TPL?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library

In the past, I've created the main thread of a service using the Thread object.  Now I'm attempting to update it to the TPL.  Unfortunately, the service ends after one pass in my loop.  What do I need to do to keep the Task alive?

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _workerThread = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("go");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        });
    }
```

More info:

In order to debug the service, I've set a flag to start the service as a console app if Environment.UserInteractive is set to true.  So I guess I need it to keep going in console mode as well as a service.

Comment: What do you mean by "ends"? That should work fine.  (although you'll want `TaskOptions.LongRunning`)

Comment: Have you checked your EventLogs for errors, because services don't "end" unless stopped

Comment: @DavidG: I don't think so; the Service Control Manager always keeps a thread of its own running, so the service shouldn't need to do so.  But that would be a Win32 thread, not a .NET thread; perhaps .NET automatically exits the process when the last .NET thread exits, even if there are Win32 threads still running?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm not sure, been a few months since I've had to work on a service app. Tried digging out some code but they all start timers. Going to have a play now...

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, there's nothing wrong with the code posted. It must be ending due to some sort of unhandled exception elsewhere.

Comment: The problem might be the use of Console.WriteLine.  IIRC, service processes are run without a console, so writing to standard output can potentially cause a crash.  (It is possible that .NET guarantees to generate a console for you if you don't already have one, I don't know.)

Comment: Replace the Thread.Sleep with Task.Delay, add an async tag on your method and use await. That should work

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `Thread`, it is a foreground thread by default (its [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground) is set to `false`). What that means is that your console application won't end until the thread does, even if `Main` returns before that.

`Task`s, on the other hand, run on the thread pool, which contains only background threads. This means that when your `Main` returns, the application will exit, even if there is some `Task` still running.

You can fix this by `Wait`ing on the `Task` at the end of your `Main`.